# Как скомпилировать динамическую С++ библиотеку для списка платформ с CMAKE?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, cmake, jni

Я реально не могу найти примеры. Как только не искал. [Официальная документация](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/) написана так, что не понятно вообще ничего! Набор символов.

Мне нужно всего лишь скомпилировать библиотеку .cpp сразу для всех нужных мне платформ, как минимум ARM, x86, x86_64, Linux x86, Linux x86_64 для последующего использования в Java через JNI. Желательно, чтобы одним нажатием готовые .dll раскладывались в папки вида libs/Win/x86, .so в папки вида libs/Linux/arm.

Для компиляции использую Clion. Но у этого cmake столько параметров и все они работают не так, как хотелось бы. Помогите разобраться.